# Print half page or a quarter page

Tags: pdf, printing, adobe-reader

I have a PDF which contains 4 powerpoint diapositives per sheet in landscape mode:

[image]

Is there a way to tell adobe reader to print half page for each paper sheet? I would like that Diapositive 1 and 2 stay in one A4 sheet, and Diapositive 3 and 4 stay in another A4 sheet.

I also have another PDF like the previous one, but diapositives are in another order:

[image]

Is there a way to tell adobe reader to print one quarter page for each paper sheet? So that Diapositive 1, 2, 3, 4 come each in a different sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Both the below methods worked for me:

1. Using Acrobat Pro you can crop the page and convert it into four different slides. After that you can print each slide with the size option set to "fit".
2. Print from Adobe reader after selecting "Poster" option under "Page Sizing and Handling" in the print window. But you have to set the value for "Tile Scale" after trial & error method. It worked for me with "Tile Scale"=190%.

Answer (score 1):

In my installation, I have a couple buttons under Page Sizing & Handling. One of those says Poster and does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this - I can't guarantee that it will work: print at 200% (4x) to PDF. The percentage may be different - try and find out! Then each slide could come out in one page, but maybe not in the right order. Then you can print two slides per page, either to PDF or to paper.

My first thought was this, for the first image only: you could print at 144% (double size) and than 1 and 2 should be printed full page. If it's 144% or 142 or something else, you have to try. I remember doing something like this in the past, when printing to A3. You may have to change printing to landscape or portrait because the print has to be rotated for this to work.

I don't know what will happen with image quality, as these slides are exported as JPEG probably. Each save could deteriorate the image quality, so if you can set it, set it high for inbetween runs.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the page proportions to 400% doesn't help, it prints the exact same document :(

Comment: I can get the first slide to print at full size on A4, but not the rest. Maybe you need something like Adobe Acrobat Professional? I believe OpenPDF has a pdf editor as well: http://sourceforge.net/projects/openpdf/

Comment: Even with Acrobat Pro it doesn't work, I set 400% but when I print it generates another PDF file identical to the one I have

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu right now, use Document Viewer, a simple PDF viewer. I can set it to print to 200% (not 400!) and it prints out one slide from a page with four on it.

Comment: I can't try it on Ubuntu (or any other linux-based system) right now, with acrobat it doesn't work either setting the zoom to 200% or 400%

Comment: Try this and export the images from the pdf. http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/extract-images-pdf-files-save-windows/ Acrobat has a similar function to extract images. Then import them into Word or Acrobat.